# Cannot prevent my service from registering with Eureka

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

I have a Spring Boot application with the following config:

```
eureka:
  client:
    enabled: true
    registerWithEureka: false
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://somehost:9999/eureka/
  registration:
    enabled: false
```

My service makes use of Eureka to discover external services, but I don't want it to register with Eureka. Despite the above config I still see the following in my logs, which is odd:

```
DiscoveryClient - Not registering with Eureka server per configuration
...
EurekaServiceRegistry - Registering application foo with eureka with status UP
```

The first log line makes sense - it's what I want. However, the second log line doesn't make sense given the config. Am I missing a setting?

Comment: Your configuration is right. Actual registration with eureka server will not occur. The second log just says that what happened in your local process.

Comment: Interesting. I wasn't able to confirm at the time I posted as the Eureka server I use was not available, but after running my service and checking the /eureka/apps endpoint I can see my service is not actually registered. If you'd like to post your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: What's the point of `eureka.client.enabled=true` if you're not gonna register with Eureka server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't missing anything and your configuration is right. The second log just says that what happened in your local process.

The all periodic tasks that are related to actual registration process (ex heartbeat, instance info replication) with Eureka server are not scheduled by your configuration. So registration with Eureka server will not happen.